# Ticks on scaleTime() not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to set up a timescale with a domain of 2 dates 40 days apart. My data being:

```
[
   {
      "date": "Wed Jul 06 2016 16:44:14 GMT-0400",
      "dailyVerified": 44,
      "totalVerified": 206
   },
   // other data would go here...
   {
      "date": "Sun Aug 14 2016 16:44:14 GMT-0400",
      "dailyVerified": 27,
      "totalVerified": 2109
   }
]
```

When trying to set the `scale.ticks(x)`, it doesn't seem to do anything. Code is:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime();

x
  .domain([firstDate, lastDate])
  .range([0, 600])
  .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(3))
```

[For full code see jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xakabirotu/edit?js,output).

I try setting the ticks to one every 3 days, just like in the api docs but it doesn't seem to do anything - ticks are still split by week. Any ideas why? Is it cause I set the domain incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was trying to set ticks on the *axis* instead of the *scale*. So instead of:

```
x.ticks(d3.timeDay.every(5))
```

I needed to do:

```
const xA = d3.axisBottom(x);
// set the ticks on the axis
xA.ticks(d3.axisBottom(x))
```